# Porting Xcode(iOS) code to eclipse(android) in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, xcode, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I implemented my game in xcode using cocos2d-x templates. It works absolutely fine. Then i tried to port the same code to eclipse. I created a new project using the shell command of cocos2d-x and built the project. Then i converted the created project to run as C/C++ code as i would normally do for cocos2d-x. Then i copied all the code files/resources from my xcode project to eclipse project. I updated my Android.mk file according(added the new src files). It compiled correctly, installed the emulator successfully but then it crashes showing this error message in log:

```
07-11 10:29:38.846: D/libEGL(534): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-11 10:29:38.856: D/libEGL(534): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-11 10:29:39.166: A/libc(534): @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree
07-11 10:29:39.166: A/libc(534): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think u are doing combined Java and C++ projects in Eclipse. I am not able to get **code-assitence and auto debug code** feature while programming in eclipse? i.e. Suppose you want to type `cocos2d::CCSprite * _ship;`. After writing **coc** and pressing **Ctrl + Space** are you getting code assist? I am not getting this feature I used to have this feature while programming in **Java**. What can be the problem? I have configured all **Paths and Symbols(includes)**.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra steps involved with getting cocos2d-x running in the emulator. Have you followed those steps? (I can't remember off the top, but I think you have to make sure the OpenGL hardware acceleration feature is enabled on your virtual device, and there might also be some code you need to patch into your project.)

I tried performing those steps, but never got it to run and wasn't persistent enough to stick with it since I happen to have an Android phone anyway.